# cleaning a list to only keep integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bear with me, i am in the early stages of learning to code. I am having trouble with my last guideline.

The function clean should do the following:

-remove missing items (e.g.  1,2,,3)

-remove items marked with None or are the empty string
-remove items that are not numbers

-However, if the item is a string, but a valid number, keep it (e.g. '1.1', '   3  ')

-Convert each valid number into a float

so far i have

```
def clean(csv_list):
  no_none = list(filter(None, csv_list))
  only_numbs = list(filter(str.isdigit, no_none))
return only_numbs
```

I am stuck at figuring out how to keep strings that represent integers within the list.

```
csv = "a, 1, '-2', 2.35, None,, 4, True"
print(clean(csv))
# output is [1.0, -2.0, 2.35, 4.0]
```

Comment: It looks like your code will also fail for:
1. floats represented as strings
2. integers that are surrounded by whitespace characters
I think you should try and clean up the elements first with `strip()`, then think about filtering.

Comment: The question title says you want integers, but the question text says you want floats. Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Based on the name of your variables, it seems as if you should split the string on comma.

Comment: As far as I can see, each step of your program is covered in other Stack Overflow questions, as well as in on-line tutorials.  Search for (1) How to read a CSV file; (2) How to extract numbers from a line of input.

Comment: Yes, you should `import csv` and use `csv.reader` to read lines, rather than writing your own CSV parser. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Shortly with `re.findall` function:

```
import re

s = "a, 1, '-2', 2.35, None,, 4, True"
numbers = [float(n) for n in re.findall(r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)]
print(numbers)    # [1.0, -2.0, 2.35, 4.0]
```

Comment: This won't match floats like `1e3 == 1000.0`.